# How to embed pdf files into browser with links in .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, razor

I'm new to MVC and would like to find out how to view PDF files.  Specifically, I have a bunch of PDF files on server.  I would like to render links to those PDF files using MVC and allow the user to click on a link to view the PDF file in a browser.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some javascript or pdf readers controll.

Look at : http://viewerjs.org/